# Is there any way we can list only ciphers with “YES” in mentioned script

Tags: bash, shell, openssl

Is there any way we can list only ciphers with "YES" using below mentioned script . Script looks working but it gives huge lists including ciphers YES & NO.It will be great if we can filter o/p (echo $result) by using grep within script but not sure how to get through.
Appreciate help on this as I have to run script and looks for ciphers enabled in Prod servers

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# OpenSSL requires the port number.
SERVER=$1
DELAY=1
ciphers=$(openssl ciphers 'ALL:eNULL' | sed -e 's/:/ /g')

echo Obtaining cipher list from $(openssl version).

for cipher in ${ciphers[@]}
do
echo -n Testing $cipher...
result=$(echo -n | openssl s_client -cipher "$cipher" -connect $SERVER 2>&1)
if [[ "$result" =~ ":error:" ]] ; then
  error=$(echo -n $result | cut -d':' -f6)
  echo NO \($error\)
else
  if [[ "$result" =~ "Cipher is ${cipher}" || "$result" =~ "Cipher    :" ]] ; then
    echo YES
  else
    echo UNKNOWN RESPONSE
    echo $result
  fi
fi
sleep $DELAY
done
```

Comment: It's probably simplest just to pipe the output of the script through an appropriate grep command. However, if you're always going to filter them out, why not just create a version of the script that has all the `echo` commands you are not interested in deleted?

Comment: Thanks jhnc. as final result stored in result variable . Hence greping on variable result to extract only those ciphers with YES is something I am not sure. For eg I tired  echo $reault| grep -i “YES” . Any suggestions on this